React Native error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
react-native run-android
(node:24024) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)
info Installing the app...
info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit
: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\��ä��\Sample\Sample\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\��ä��.gradle\caches\8.6\scripts
\43hmaps6tn7iqtkdz21pmdj39).                                                                                                                                   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 66

Try:



Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 935ms
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an ex
ception. * What went wrong: Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\��ä��\Sample\Sample\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\��ä��.gradle\caches\8.6\scripts\43hmaps6tn7iqtkdz21pmdj39). > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 66 * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 935ms.                                                                           info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Is it an error because the ��ä�� part is not in English?
how can i solve this problem? please help
